# Math Processing Error in solution.

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

I'm not sure if this is the right place to report this.

For this particular [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477125/how-to-prove-algebraic-structure-of-the-perfect-shuffle/477766#477766), whenever I first load it, I get a [Math Processing Error] only for my solution (question displays fine). When I proceed to click the edit button, it displays properly. Saving it then causes the solution to display fine.

I've noticed that the first few Latex display fine, so a possibility is that it doesn't like the \not \equiv code that appears later.

I'm not sure if this happens for anyone else, so I've included a screenshot. (Ugh, I don't know how to load images, so here's the [link](http://cl.ly/image/1W1l063D1T1e) )

[image: screenshot]

Any reason why it's only occurring for this problem?

Comment: It looks as if a cache has gone bad. Try refreshing or restarting your browser. That often reloads the caches.

Comment: I've been having MathJax issues all day. I just got a slew of Math Processing Errors on the front page. I'm thinking it's an error with the interpreter because there have been instances when stuff enclosed in dollar signs has not even been interpreted as LaTeX code and was just displayed in plain text (with the dollar signs enveloping it).